# run orbbec astra sensor on ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

can orbbec astra camera run with ros ? if it can how to do it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227981/run-orbbec-astra-sensor-on-ros/) by [rebirth](https://answers.ros.org/users/26130/rebirth/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From [Orbbec Astra on ROS](https://3dclub.orbbec3d.com/t/orbbec-astra-on-ros/162) fi it seems like these cameras are OpenNI compatible?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rebirth](https://answers.ros.org/users/26130/rebirth/) on 2016-03-02**:
yes, it compatible with openni, i already test using its sdk that use openni. but ros is still fail somehow